# Foreign keys in Entity Framework not updating correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having trouble with foreign key relationships in the entity framework. I have two tables: `Persons` and `Countries`. `Persons` has a foreign key column to `CountryId`.

As the `Countries` table rarely changes, I want to fetch its data only once, dispose the `DatabaseContext`, and keep the list of `Countries` cached somewhere. This is where I am running into problems.

The entity framework seems to want you to open a database context, add/edit rows as needed, then close the database context. If you open, fetch data, close; and then later open, save data, close; it has trouble.

So my POCO objects look like this:

```
public class Country {
    public int CountryId {get; set; }
    public String Name {get; set; }
}

public Person {
    public int PersonId {get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country {get; set; }
}
```

Then, I try to create a new person like this:

```
Country[] countries;
using (var dt = new DatabaseContext())
{
    countries= dt.Countries.ToArray();
}

Person person = new Person();
person.Country = countries[0];
using (var dt = new DatabaseContext()) { 
    dt.Entities.Add(person);
    dt.SaveChanges();
}
```

On save, the entity framework creates a new row in the `Countries` table with the same name as `countries[0]`, but a new, incremented ID. This is obviously not the desired outcome - the person should have its `Country_CountryId` field set to the id of `countries[0]`, and a new row should not be created.

How do I solve this? I think one solution would be to force the entity framework to *not* create a new row when it is given an object that already has its primary key set. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you at least search little bit on Internet before you put quite big effort to describe the issue because this is very common problem asked every few days.

`Add` method adds all entities in the entity graph. So if you connect `country` to `person` and `country` is not attached to current context, calling `Add` on the `person` will mark both `person` and `country` as new entities for insertion. If you don't want `country` to be inserted you must tell EF that `country` is not a new entity:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Country = countries[0];
using (var dt = new DatabaseContext()) { 
    dt.Entities.Add(person);
    dt.Entry(person.Country).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dt.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution is not ideal as it requires the programmer to set `EntityState.Modified` for each child entity - I feel like this will lead to problems, and breaks encapsulation. Is there any way to intercept `Add` at the point where it attaches the untracked objects?

Comment: This solution is the correct and supposed way to do that. You are going to persist entity graph not loaded by EF so you must tell EF what changes in relations were made. The `Add` method cannot be intercepted. It even cannot be overriden because it is not virtual.

Comment: I think this is quite a big problem - your solution would be no good for our real database, where `Person` holds references to 5 different countries, some types, relationship definitions and so on. To write `EntityState.Modified` for all of these would take many lines of code, and would be bad to maintain. However, I can't think better solution.

Comment: So make it more automated. The book [Programming DbContext](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do) provides step by step guide to creating custom interface which will define `State` property. By implementing this interface in every entity and using the `State` property in your application logic you will be able to set state correctly on all objects within one loop in overriden `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding the following two methods to my `DatabaseContext` class:

```
public void Add(object target)
{
    this.Set(target.GetType()).Attach(target);
    this.Entry(target).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
}

public void Modify(object target)
{
    this.Set(target.GetType()).Attach(target);
    this.Entry(target).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: This is so confusing. For some reason, the `Add` method is working, but `Modify` isn't.